# How can I use Fiddler to supply authentication information for logging into Crucible?

Tags: fiddler

My manager and the company I work for currently use a program called Crucible and Fish Eye to generate graphs and show data for code commits, code coverage, repository data etc.

My manager would like me to come up with some way of querying the database (the database that I only have access to through crucible).  He suggested that I use a program called Fiddler to generate an HTTP Request in order to GET, POST, and PUT data.

I have attempted to do this but I am not able to get data, because I do not know how to login to crucible FROM Fiddler.

Do you know if there's an authentication that I can set from Fiddler to supply the username and password to my Crucible account, or is there a different way around this?

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to use Postman instead of Fiddler. It helps you with different types of authentication schemes.

If your webservice supports basic authentication then you can add the authentication header manually or automatically as follows. Assume your username is "foo" and your password is "bar". Combine them as in "foo:bar" and encode them base64 to "Zm9vOmJhcg==" (https://www.base64encode.org/).

Now go to the Composer in Fiddler and add the following header:

```
Authorization: Basic Zm9vOmJhcg==
```

That should do it. You can also do this automatically with FiddlerScript.